# How to deduct annual leave entitlement?

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables as follows

**employee table**

emp_num, emp_fname,emp_lname

**eleave table**

lev_id, emp_num,leave_date,resume_date

**eleave_entitlement table**

lent_id, emp_num,typ_id,annual_entitlement

**type table**

typ_id,typ_name

**query**

```
SELECT employee.emp_num, eleave_entitlement.annual_entitlement,
     datediff(eleave.resume_date,eleave.leave_date) as noOfleavedays,
     annual_entitlement - datediff(eleave.resume_date,eleave.leave_date) as LeaveBalance,
     YEAR(eleave.leave_date) as Year 
FROM employee 
     INNER JOIN eleave_entitlement ON employee.emp_num = eleave_entitlement.emp_num 
     LEFT JOIN eleave ON eleave.emp_num = employee.emp_num 
where employee.emp_num = 1
```

The above query does not give me the correct result that I'm after

This is the result getting from above query:-

```
    emp_num annual_entitlement noOfleavedays LeaveBalance   Year
    1        17                 11            6.0           2019
    1        17                  5            12.0          2019
    1        17                  2            15.0          2019
```

The require result that I am looking for is like this

```
emp_num annual_entitlement noOfleavedays LeaveBalance   Year
1        17                 11            6.0           2019
1        6                  5            12.0           2019
1        1                  2            15.0           2019
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: This is great sql I wanner know if the annual_entitlement which is 17 in table 2 is deducted every time an employee take his/her leave

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query to show available leaves.

```
   SELECT employee.emp_num
    , t1.cnt
    , datediff(eleave.resume_date,eleave.leave_date) as noOfleavedays
    , annual_entitlement - datediff(eleave.resume_date,eleave.leave_date) as LeaveBalance
    , YEAR(eleave.leave_date) as Year 
    FROM employee 
    INNER JOIN eleave_entitlement ON employee.emp_num = eleave_entitlement.emp_num 

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT emp_num, sum(datediff(eleave.resume_date,eleave.leave_date)) as cnt 
 FROM eleave group by emp_num) as t1
         ON t1.emp_num = employee.emp_num 
    LEFT JOIN eleave ON eleave.emp_num = employee.emp_num    
    where employee.emp_num = 1
```